# Error in doing drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is`

```
<script>
 $(function(){
 var xco,yco,sen,ple,pto;
document.onmouseup=function(){document.onmousemove=null;};
$(".pcre").mousedown(function(e){sen=$(this);
ple=sen.offset().left; 
 pto=sen.offset().top; 
  xco=e.clientX;
  yco=e.clientY;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e){fle=ple+e.clientX-xco;
  fto=pto+e.clientY-yco;
  sen.css("top",fto);
  sen.css("left",fle);

  });
  });


 });</script>
```

`When I move the div it moves but on mouseup nothing happens and it keeps on following mouse

Comment: Iam new to jquery ,so can you help me in using ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you using the jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/
It's like a plugin for jQuery providing tools for animations, user interactions and much more.

Example for a draggable DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/TFjB7/

You see, it's really easy:
`$('.draggable').draggable();`

You can find more examples and the documentation on http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ . Just download it and include it in your document.